# Open before opened buffer in vertical window in vim

Tags: vim

I have two opened buffers (i.e. A and B) and one window. Currently I see A, I would like to open B in vertical window. To do it in horizontal window I can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>^</kbd>, how to do it in vertical window? And how to change horizontal windows to vertical windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To display your two buffers vertically, you can use :
`:vsplit #`
or the short version
`:vs #`

To reorganize your layout from horizontal to vertical, you must use:
`<C-W>K`  : will move the current windows to to the top with a horizontal split
`<C-W>J`  : will move the current windows to to the bottom with a horizontal split

`<C-W>H` : will move the current window to the the left with a vertical split
`<C-W>L` : will move the current window to the the rigth with a vertical split

See `:help windows.txt` for more information

Comment: nice anwser, but :vsplit open my current buffer in two windows;
I have to use C+W ^ and then C-W H

Comment: @Slawosz : did you type the `#` as well ? `#`is for alternate buffer. If you have only two buffers, it should open the other buffer in the split.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `:vsplit B` to open B explicitly in the new window.

Comment: Note that if you would like the two resulting windows to be swapped you can set either `splitright` or `splitbelow` in your vimrc.

Answer (score 2):

You may use Vertical Split

> `Ctrl+Wv`

command line `:vertical split`

Answer (score 2):

- open a vertical split: [`:vs`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#%3avs)
- go to that split (assuming it's on the right: [`CTRL-W l`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#window-move-cursor)
- open buffer B there: [`:b B`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#%3ab)